# Lumpy ditra install

Tags: tile

I put down ditra in a laundry room and am noticing many lumps and also some unevenness at one of the seams. Since I am putting down 12x24” ceramic tiles I am worried that it will lead to cracking. What is the best way to handle this?

Some other background-
Before installing I removed a sheet of linoleum and thin piece of plywood. Under that was another sheet of linoleum that was glued down very solidly to the subfloor and also had several rows of staples. I was worried about asbestos because it looked pretty old and I also didn’t want to deal with the staples, so I used a fast setting fortified thinset to put the ditra over the linoleum (per the ditra manual). I used floor patch to level a couple spots as well before the thinset.

The only reason I used ditra to begin with was to minimize the height of the tile as it transitions to a hardwood in the hall that is much lower. The waterproofing features of ditra were a bonus but I’d sacrifice both the height and waterproofing to avoid cracking.

The options I’m considering are:

- just trying to lay the tile and using thinset as I go to fill in the lumps and unevenness. I’ve only tiled once before and I’m not super confident that I’ll do this well, plus the unevenness at the seam looks too big for that ( probably 1/4” with the tile over it).
- pouring a self leveling compound over the ditra
- cutting out the whole subfloor and replacing it, the room is only abou 35 sq feet

Are there other options, or advice for which of these would be best?

Comment: Any chance of posting pictures...especially the "lumps"?

Comment: "*My hump, my hump, my hump
My lovely little lumps,*"  Probably best, less headache? to remove and start over. Not a good idea to "*lay the tile and using thinset as I go to fill in the lumps and unevenness.*"